# How to integrate Urban airship using Xcode 6

Tags: ios

I follow all guideline steps of urban airship support to integrate in IOS project , but still getting error, can anyone help me.

Comment: No, honestly, no one can help you.  Not without a proper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting odd errors related to a UI file and you're using the most recent iOS SDK version, you'll want to include UIKit/UIKit.h in your pre-compile header.

Otherwise, going to need more detail.